# Saw a dead person on the way to work

Tags: time-off, personal-problems, japan

On the way to work today, I saw a dead person at a train station where my train stopped. This has affected me more than I expected. I am shaking and trying to hold my tears while trying to write code at work.

I am working abroad in Japan. Taking the day off would mean losing a holiday day,  which is just not an option for me.

I have no idea what to do, and I do not have any close friend at work. **How to cope with this at the workplace?**

Comment: I wish I had seen your question sooner. I hope my answer below helps you. I hope you will feel better soon.

Comment: I can't believe I have to post this but apparently I do - if you are going to add a comment and can't say anything nice, e̶n̶j̶o̶y̶ ̶b̶e̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶s̶u̶s̶p̶e̶n̶d̶e̶d̶
  __do not say anything at all__.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it pertains to matters outside of the workplace.

Comment: @JimG Matter outside the workplace affects the OP *in* the workplace. This happens to most of us in the workplace, while the specific details of the "matter" may vary. Doesn't seem off-topic here.

Answer (score 25):

**Ask your manager what to do.**

Don't assume that taking the day off is not an option. If you don't ask, you will never know. I am sure your manager will be able to figure out some alternatives. If you are concerned about losing a holiday day, you could suggest taking a "reverse comp-off", whereby you take the day off today and come in to work on a future holiday.

If I were your manager, I would rather focus on what can help you cope with the situation than worry about the holiday policy. I certainly wouldn't want you to be worried about work while shaking and trying to hold tears. If I found out about it later, I would be absolutely horrified.

Comment: perhaps compassionate leave

Comment: ..  or sick leave

Comment: Japan has a [relatively high suicide rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_in_Japan) so your manager will either have experience or should have guidance to share with personnel on these matters.

Comment: @Marzipanherz Normally one would take one of the "conventional" leaves in this situation. However, I think in this case, since the OP is working abroad, he probably wants to accumulate his leaves so he can take them in one go to be with his family in his home country. Hence I suggested the reverse comp-off, I have now edited to make this clearer. Thanks for  your feedback.